# What does the number in eslint rule arrays mean?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm totally new to eslint configurations. I'm using tslint for typescript for quite a while now so I'm familiar with the concept.

eslint uses for many rules a syntax like

```
"no-cond-assign": [2, "always"]
```

or just

```
"no-constant-condition": 2
```

What does the number mean? The documentation is pretty huge and I'm not able to google or find it in the docs on the fly

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I've found it myself by using another number than 0,1 or 2. I defines the severity of a rule.

```
Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warning, 2 = error (you passed "3").
```

Documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules

Comment: And recently the ESLint people made this all transparent by allowing use of "off", "warn", and "error".

Comment: Can be found in the current official docs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

Comment: Updated link to the specific related docs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules